# Corporate Identity - I feel something is not right

Tags: logo, critique, design-principles, branding

The brand is for a safebox-custoding company.

I think I am close to finish the design. **However, I feel like it's still lacking something.** I don't know what it is. It's a gut/eye feeling.

I wonder if anyone could give me his opinion + suggestions. Please, do not hesitate. **Even nitpicking would be appreciated**.

---

**REGARDING THE DESIGN CHOICES**

1. FJ stands for the initials. Unchangeable, of course.
2. Iconography. I tried to synthesise the initials with the concept of security (shield + safebox) and, in a negligible way, with a golden bar. It's the second of 3 versions, and the one they chose. Still able to do light/considerable changes though. I feel like it's so dull, so obvious.
3. Palette. They requested firmly blue + orange. I tried to tweak them, but sincerely, the orange wont do for the "discretion" aspect they wanted too... Any thoughts? ​
4. I don't think there is a problem by having them both as corporative colors. Just not both at the same time. Perhaps black-blue as a background-only thing?
5. Fonts. A display font for the isotipe + another one for the must-be-legible bla bla. Pretty standard.

**Please, judge my elections.**

---

**ATTACHMENTS**

> [image: Page1 + Initial sketches]
> [image: Fonts + Palette. Pending pantone.]
> [image: Negative.v.1]
> [image: Positive.v.1]
> [image: Positive.v.2. Two colors. Not of my liking...The contrast is not goo]
> [image: BW][image: OneXColorVersion]
> [image: SizeVariants]

Comment: Use the internal tools to post an image. Not a random link.

Comment: That link is a shared Drive folder. There's several pages, so I didn't know what to do. It's my first post, my apologies. I'll try do as requested.

Comment: You could choose one representative example of the problem you are facing. Make a screen capture or make an export. Also, try to focus on one problem at a time. This forum tries to address specific questions that might help someone else in the future with a similar case.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what's wrong with it... I tried to apply all design principles I learned, but I'm not getting anything that professional... So I just thought about asking some experienced feedback.

Comment: The straight line at the top of the logo bothers me. I’m seeing an open book rather than a safe, and it’s at least in part because the top line doesn’t act like it would on a three-dimensional cube.

Comment: Questions like this are difficult to answer with anything but personal opinion - and opinions depend upon personal tastes rather than facts.  For what it's worth, I think the logo is a bit obvious, a bit banal, or even clichéd perhaps.  Does it literally have to represent a safe/shield?

Comment: @Znivy - perhaps you might be able to try something which is more abstract, and  less obvious.

Comment: @BillyKerr, sorry, I misclicked and deleted my comment. Now I realise that probably the FJ in the logo isn't that clear. The middle column + handle forms the F. And the side one the J. But yeah, I agree. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: I don't *really* see a question here. Merely asking for **opinions** with no direct, answerable, question. I think this is far, far, too broad to be answered effectively in any way. This may be better suited to a "discussion form" which this isn't, or in Chat here. Offhand.. I wouldn't have chosen *that* blue with *that* orange -- values are too similar to be dynamic. The angle of the "box" makes it look like slightly open doors, not a box.

Comment: Thank you all. I wanted to ask about typography, the palette, the creativity, the way I developed the logo, etc. and those are the points you're making. I find them helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Opinions

The shield: A refrigerator or a book is not the most assuring mark for security business. Get a medieval shield, paint on it a massive lock or a opening handle of the same style as for example Fort Knox vaults have. Or preferably draw a sturdy abstract symbol. No matter what, but it must look sturdy.

Text: No text tricks! Even the Italics is too much. This is not cosmetics nor decoration, this is strength and reliability. Start from something like this:

[image]

Or from this:

[image]

The mark can as well be above the name or it can be a frame for the texts. Here's a brutal mark inserted, too. An abstract symbol would be better.

(sorry for shortening the name, but talking and writing shortly is a virtue where I live)

Comment: Thank you! I will reconsider to my type choices. The straight one you choose is definetely better at comunicating the values I have in mind. Shame that I can't change the palette, as black serves very well too.

Answer (score -1):

Reduce the size of the mark. Increase the size of the brand type so that it's line length matches the supporting text. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried before, but i felt like it was disproportionated. Thank you, nevertheless!!